# How to find and replace multiple line texts in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have a text file named "data" with the content:

```
a
b
c
abc
```

I'd like to find all "abc" (doesn't need to be on the same line) and replace the leading "a" to "A". Here "b" can be any character (one or more) but not 'c'.

(This is a simplification of my actual use case.)

I thought this perl command would do

```
perl -pi.bak -e 's/a([^c]+?)c/A\1c/mg' data
```

With this 'data' was changed to:

```
a
b
c
Abc
```

I was expecting:

```
A
b
c
Abc
```

I'm not sure why perl missed the first occurrence (on line 1-3).

Let me know if you spot anything wrong with my perl command or you know a working alternative. Much appreciated.

Comment: You need `perl -0777pe 's/a([^c]+)c/A$1c/g'` or `perl -0pe 's/a([^c]+)c/A$1c/g'`

Comment: (You didn't need to delete the other question. Even duplicate questions can help people, since they might find the closed question in a search, and that will lead them to the answer.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're reading a line at a time, applying the code to that one line. It can't possibly match across multiple lines. The simple solution is to tell `perl` to treat the entire file as one line using `-0777`.

```sh
perl -i.bak -0777pe's/a([^c]+c)/A$1/g' data
```

- Replaced the incorrect `\1` with `$1`.
- Removed the useless `/m`. It only affects `^` and `$`, but you don't use those.
- Removed the useless non-greedy modifier.
- Moved the `c` into the capture to avoid repeating it.

Comment: For a more flexible solution might consider using `\U$1\E$2` and capture the first match.